# Jwt with multiple model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I use Lavarel 5.2 framework with jwt for authorization 
jwt takes user info form token just with one model,
now how can i parse user token with jwt on multiple model?

For sample when i use customer token in a api jwt parse that token from customer model , default guard should be customer

 `auth.php` :

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'operator',
    'passwords' => 'operators',
],

'guards' => [
    'operator' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'operators',
    ],
    'customer' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'customers',
    ],
    'biker' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'bikers',
    ]
],

'providers' => [
    'operators' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Http\Services\Auth\Model\User::class,
    ],
    'customers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Http\Aggregate\Customer\Model\Customer::class,
    ],
    'bikers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Http\Aggregate\Biker\Model\Biker::class,
    ]
],
```

Comment: please help me friends

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Think about how you might reword it to something that people can help you with.

Comment: now i think is clear

Comment: thanks for score friends , but i hope you help me for this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a separate middleware like AuthModel. In that you can set the config to take which providers like the below,

```
Config::set('auth.providers.users.model',\App\Models\Customer::class);
```

If you want to use multiple models, then need to use if conditions to check which url can access which models. It can be like,

```
if(url == '/customer/api/') {
 Config::set('auth.providers.users.model',\App\Models\Customer::class);
} else if(url == '/biker/api/') {
 Config::set('auth.providers.users.model',\App\Models\Biker::class);
}
```

In the above example, I have used url just for example, so get it from the request.

Comment: Hi can you please review this question related to your answer and tell me what do think about it [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212086/lravel-5-4-jwt-api-with-multi-auth-on-two-tables-one-works-the-other-not)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `__construct` function in each of your controllers as follows. So that jwt know which model to authenticate.

**BikerController**

```
function __construct()
{
    Config::set('jwt.user', Biker::class);
    Config::set('auth.providers', ['users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Biker::class,
        ]]);
}
```

**CustomerController**

```
function __construct()
{
    Config::set('jwt.user', Customer::class);
    Config::set('auth.providers', ['users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Customer::class,
        ]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. Tested on Laravel 6

User Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Notifiable;

    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string';

    protected $fillable =
    [
    
    ];

    protected $hidden =
    [
        'password',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at'
    ];

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
      
    }
}
```

Teacher Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class Teacher extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Notifiable;

    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string';

    protected $fillable =
    [
       
    ];

    protected $hidden =
    [
        'password',
        'oldpassword',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at'
    ];

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
       
    }
}
```

config/auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users'
        ],
        'teacher-api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'teachers'
        ],
    ],
```

AuthController function :

```
   if (
        $request->getRequestUri() ===
        'OTHER_AUTH_ROUTE'
    ) {
        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password']);
        $token = Auth::shouldUse('teacher-api');
        $token = Auth::attempt($credentials);
        if (!$token) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }
        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }
    $credentials = $request->only([USERNAME, 'password']);
    $token = Auth::attempt($credentials);
    if (!$token) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }
    return $this->respondWithToken($token);
```

Hope this can help you all at future

Answer (score 0):

*Laravel 8 compatible*

For others still looking for a clean solution:

I would suggest manually configure the providers and guards in config/auth.php and not programmatically change any providers.

The next thing to make sure the right JWTSubject auth model is used, is to create different Middleware (don't forget to specify it in Kernel.php under `$routeMiddleware`) for a group of routes that has to be only accessible by a specific guard/auth model. Then a middleware handle function could look like this for a Manager model:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {
    if (!($request->user('managers'))) abort(401);

    Auth::shouldUse('managers');

    return $next($request);
}
```

Then create another middleware for, let's say an Employee model and change the 'managers' guard value to 'employees' which you configured in config/auth.php.

In your routes/api.php you can specify a route group using (e.g.):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'management'], function() { });
```

In order to make this all work correctly, specify the guard when the `auth()->attempt()` function is called, e.g. `auth('managers')->attempt($credentials))`.