# Multiple table authentication with lumen and JWT-Auth, JWTGuard missing parameter second parameter

Tags: laravel, lumen, multi-user, jwt

I recently started developing an application with Lumen and JWT-Auth. I don't have much experience with PHP.

My app has 2 types of Users both need Authentication.

Initially I started following [iwader's guide](https://iwader.co.uk/post/tymon-jwt-auth-with-lumen-5-2), but then I wanted to extend to use 2 different guards for my 2 different tables. So I followed [this simple extension](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/792#issuecomment-238415989), since this is for Laravel I assumed it'll also work with Lumen.

After applying the changes mentioned I am getting this error.

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTGuard::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given, called in ~/Sites/jobb-app-api/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Providers/AbstractServiceProvider.php on line 97

If someone else knows how to resolve this issue please let me know thanks.

Comment: please read this thread and understand the issue with 2 tables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39363901/jwt-with-multiple-model

Answer (score 0):

you can use that

```
Config::set('auth.model', App\Customer::class);
```

Tables and other db things you should have defined in models, so above entry should do work

Comment: where should I include this